# MySQL Duplicating Row Results in Table When Searching Across Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in a mySQL db one for users, one for colours and one for the linking of the users to the colours

```
Table 1 users
==============
ID | Name
--------------
1  | John
2  | Jayne
3  | Fred

Table 2 colours
==============
ID | Colour
--------------
1  | Blue
2  | Red
3  | Yellow

Table 3 link
==============
ID | Name | Colour
--------------
1  | 1    | 1
2  | 1    | 2
3  | 2    | 1
4  | 3    | 2
5  | 3    | 3
```

As you can see, some users have more than one favourite colour (yeah, i know, how annoying).

At the moment, I can show them in a table, with their favourite colour(s) in a column.

BUT, I want to be able to filter the table results by colour.

I can do it no problem with having a filter of just one colour, BUT the problem comes along with two colours.

If I want to see which user has selected for example Blue AND Red, I get a result of zero.

How can I get this result, without creating a search which results in each row being dedicated to a colour and then in turn showing the same user twice (one for red one for blue).

I hope this makes sense

THANKS IN ADVANCE

EDIT

An example query I have used is

```
SELECT * FROM users, colours, link WHERE users.id = link.name AND link.colour = colours.id
```

Alternatively to show for specific colour

```
SELECT * FROM users, colours, link WHERE users.id = link.name AND link.colour = colours.id AND link.colour = 1
```

But for double filter which shows duplicates

```
SELECT * FROM users, colours, link WHERE users.id = link.name AND link.colour = colours.id AND link.colour = 1 OR link.colour = 2
```

Comment: Please show as much of your query you can

Comment: I have edited to show queries used

Comment: First you should use JOIN clause when connecting table, Two I'm not quiet sure if i understand your question but look [this Sql FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df8c/5) and see if that's what you want to do...

Comment: That looks about right @AleksandarMiladinovic, but can you explain the part where its featuring "L" and "L2"

Comment: @MattEarly Hi, I edit my previous answer, I think that this is better solution, so you can test... You can see new query at the bottom of my answer I just add them there. GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that looks right here is the code:

```
SELECT Name FROM users
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(Name) AS Name 
             FROM link L
             WHERE 2 IN (SELECT Colour FROM link L2 WHERE L.Name = L2.Name)
             AND 1 IN (SELECT Colour FROM link L2 WHERE L.Name = L2.Name))
```

And now let me try to explain what L and L2 are... First sorry for my English I'll do my best to make a sense for you...

We make subquery on the same table here so we need to use alias for the table. Alias we use to give temporary name table or column which will be used only for that query.

Example for alias is when we select some column from table (**Price** and **Quantity**) and let's say we want to calculate Price * quantity and SELECT that column as **total** (total will be the name of that column in table which we return after we execute the query). Column name **total** well be give alias. we crate alias like:

```
 SELECT Price, Quantity, (Price * Quantity) AS **total**
 FROM t1...
```

That will return table with three column Price, Quantity, Total... if we don't use this **AS total** the name of that column will be Price * Quantity...

So here we use L and L2 just to know which column Name is from which part of SELECT query. If we wouldn't use alias in subquery

```
 SELECT Colour FROM link L2 WHERE L.Name = L2.Name
```

we would have problem because subquery which locks like this:

```
 SELECT Colour FROM link WHERE Name = Name
```

Doesn't make a a lot of sense, isn't it?

So basically we temporary rename table in this query because we need to know which column from which table we compere whit other one, in other way database will have a problem what to select...

I hope this make a sense for you. If you have any further question fill free to ask I will do my best to try to explain it to you.

I hope i didn't make it more complicated than it is...

GL!

**EDIT**

Hi there again, i worked something and and i figured out that your question probably have better answer than the first i give you... Hope it's not too late!

```
 SELECT u.Name
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN link L
 ON u.ID = L.Name
 INNER JOIN link l2
 ON L.Name = L2.Name
 WHERE L.Colour = 2 AND L2.Colour = 1
```

Look [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df8c/12) for that...